Does the EVP_KEY created by OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey need to be manually freed?
Does this code (ignoring lack of error handling) leak with OpenSSL 3.0?
EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
BIO *public_key_file = BIO_new_file("public.pem", "r");
OSSL_DECODER_CTX *dctx = OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(
    &pkey, "PEM", NULL, "EC",
    OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_PUBLIC_KEY | OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_DOMAIN_PARAMETERS,
    NULL, NULL
)};
OSSL_DECODER_from_bio(dctx, public_key_file);

// ...

BIO_free(public_key_file);
OSSL_DECODER_CTX_free(dctx);

Or, does it require an additional EVP_PKEY_free(pkey)?
The documentation makes no mention of whether the caller needs to free the key.

IME OpenSSL generally requires you to free objects that the documentation doesn't explicitly say another object takes "ownership" of.  The easiest way to be sure:  run both versions under something like Valgrind.  If the version of code that calls EVP_PKEY_free(pkey) doesn't have double free errors, and the version of code that fails to call EVP_PKEY_free(pkey) has memory leaks, they you need to call EVP_PKEY_free(pkey).  Conversely, if code that does call EVP_PKEY_free(pkey) has double free errors and/or crashed, then you shouldn't call EVP_PKEY_free(pkey).

Leak_DefinitelyLost
  2,653 (152 direct, 2,501 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 34 of 34
    0x4848899 malloc 
    0x4A1A5DD CRYPTO_zalloc 
    0x4A07FE3 EVP_PKEY_new 
    0x49CD1EB \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x49CC722 \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x4ABD857 \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x49CC95A \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x4ABEF97 \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x49CC95A \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x4ABE8EB \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x49CC95A \usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libcrypto.so.3 
    0x49CCC30 OSSL_DECODER_from_bio

So that's a "yes" but only after it has been loaded by a later call. OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey itself does not allocate the key.
